# amazon AWS - download images from web and manipulate them

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, image-processing

I want to build a little project.

Ho do i do this:

1) automatically download RGB image from a known internet address to amazon AWS.

2) convert the image to grayscale (eventually will do more advanced image processing).

3) store the grayscale image in amazon AWS.

4) be able to view / download the grayscale image in a web browser.

programming languages i know is matlab, and basic java (OOP university course).

is there any step by step guide?

where should i start?

Comment: My suggestion is that you start working on task number 1, and then you come back when you have a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for java.net.HttpURLConnection to see how to download a file using Java.

Then read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html which explains how to download and upload to Amazon S3. Here is an example of S3 in action from Java:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------     
// Amazon S3
//---------------------------------------------------------------------     
class S3 extends AmazonS3Client
 {final String bucket;
  S3(String u, String p, String Bucket)
   {super(new BasicAWSCredentials(u, p));
    bucket = Bucket;
   }
  boolean put(String k, String v)      
   {try 
     {final ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(v.toString().getBytes());
      putObject(bucket, k, b, new ObjectMetadata());
      setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be here to allow change to reduced redundancy
      changeObjectStorageClass(bucket, k, StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy);
      setObjectAcl(bucket, k, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);  // Has to be repeated because it is now a new object again
      return true; 
     }
    catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot put "+bucket+"/"+k+" to S3 because "+e);}
    return false; 
   }
  String get(String k) 
   {try 
     {final S3Object f = getObject(bucket, k);
      final BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(f.getObjectContent());  
      final StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(); 
      final byte[]b = new byte[1024];
      for(int n = i.read(b); n != -1; n = i.read(b)) {s.append(new String(b, 0, n));}
      return s.toString(); 
     }
    catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot get "+bucket+"/"+k+" from S3 because "+e);}
    return null; 
   }
  String[]list(String d) 
   {try 
     {final ObjectListing l = listObjects(bucket, d);
      final List<S3ObjectSummary> L = l.getObjectSummaries(); 
      final int n = L.size();
      final String[]s = new String[n];  
      for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       {final S3ObjectSummary k = L.get(i);
        s[i] = k.getKey();
       } 
      return s; 
     }
    catch(Exception e) {log("Cannot list "+bucket+"/"+d+" on S3 because "+e);}
    return new String[]{}; 
   }
 }
```

}

Once you have the image on Amazon S3, you can make the file publically visible and thus displayable in any web browser.